# How to return either an existing row or a default row for joined tables

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql-9.1

I am looking for a simpler query to return a row from joined tables **as if it were newly inserted with default values**, except for the primary/foreign key which ideally should be returned as NULL. This is so I can use a single data entry form to either add a new entry or edit an existing one.

I am using CodeIgniter, DB_ActiveRecord class and postgre DB driver.

The function I came up with is shown below, with the part I would like to simplify marked with a comment "How to optimize?":

```
public function get_entry()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    if ($id) {
        // Get existing entry from joined tables.
        $query = $this->db
                ->join('b', 'a.id = b.id')
                ->get_where('a', array('a.id' => $id));
    } else {
        // Get a new "default" entry from joined tables.
        // How to optimize? Ideally it would:
        // 1. Not need a transaction.
        // 2. Not insert (causes holes in the id sequence.)
        // 3. Not use a PHP trick of overlaying same-named results.
        $this->db->trans_begin();
        // Note: I modified insert() so that empty array gives "DEFAULT VALUES"
        //       and 3rd parameter gives "RETURNING ..."
        $query = $this->db
            ->insert('a', array(), 'id');
        if ($this->db->trans_status() and $query->num_rows()) {
            $id = $query->row()->id;
            $query = $this->db
                ->insert('b', array('id' => $id));
            if ($this->db->trans_status() and $query) {
                $query = $this->db
                    // Note: This trick overlays NULL onto value in id
                    ->select('*, NULL AS id')
                    ->join('b', 'a.id = b.id')
                    ->get_where('a', array('a.id' => $id));
            }
        }
        // Note: Trash the temporary insert.
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
    if ($query and $query->num_rows()) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: What does a "default entry" consist of?  Why do you need to query a database to get default values?

Comment: A "default entry" is defined by the DEFAULT keyword on each column. The tables are extremely big and are extensible (columns can be added at run time), thus I cannot hardcode the columns or the default values.

Comment: Can you just create a default row in each table with a known id? So if there is no id, you just use id=1 (or whatever) and (as you already do) set the resulting id field to null. New columns added would automatically populate the default row with the default values.

Comment: @Jerry - I would have to exclude that row from normal queries...